# Constructing an equation from OLS summary in Python.

Tags: python, excel-formula, linear-regression, summary

I want to translate the coefficients that I have found by OLS regression in Python into an equation in MS-excel.I have already built an equation but it is not giving correct results. How can I do it and where could it possibly be going wrong? Also, is there any need to consider the std. error while constructing the equation?

Comment: As a test, you might try a simple straight line for the equation as it is simpler to work with when troubleshooting any problems. After that is functioning correctly you have only to change the equation.

Comment: I tried that, but it is not giving convincing results.

Comment: Did the test work correctly using a straight line?

Comment: No, it didn't. I was expecting a result of 1.566 but what I got was -22.1. I do not understand what is it that I am missing.

Comment: Try a very simple straight line equation like "y = 2 * x +  1" so that the result is simple. In that equation, an X value of 5 should give "y = 2 * 5 + 1" which equals 11.